# Left click selection not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, selection-tools

Since I started using Blender I've never been able to left-click select anything, nor move it, nor anything. It's as if it is something that isn't supposed to work at all. The only way I've been able to select an object only by left click and drag of the mouse (same as when we copy a big amount of text or photos) and that doesn't work if it's a model with a lot of pieces since it just selects them all. I'm a beginner so the few things I've tried haven't worked possibly since I haven't done them right, but I did try a couple of commands such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, still doesn't work. Also seeing whether my objects are selectable, but nothing has worked, please help!

P.S. I'm not sure which version is my blender, possibly 3.1, but it's for sure from this year 2023

I also just tried going to the preference menu, input, and enable 3 button mouse, but it was already enabled, so I switched it on and off and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's not hard to find out which version you have. When opening up it is in the upper right corner of the _Splash Screen_ (the centered image shown at the start). Then it is at the bottom right corner of the program window in the status bar. If not, right-click on the status bar and enable the option _Blender Version_. Another place to find it: in the top menu bar, click on the Blender symbol left of _File_ and choose _About Blender_. Or you could bring up the _Splash Screen_ again from there as well. There are probably even more ways - like every software, if you search for it you can find it.